# WCF, IIS, and Endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf

Learning WCF (I know, late to the party)

I am working through Juval Lowy's Programming WCF book.  I see that I can configure multiple endpoints (including URI's) for my service.

However, when I host these in IIS, only the location of the .svc file seems to matter.  Is the multiple endpoints/addresses thing only applicable if you are self-hosting?  Am I missing something about hosting services in IIS?

Comment: I've been going through the same book and wondering exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"only the location of the .svc ", you're heading to this because baseaddress are provided by IIS in case of web-hosting (IIS hosting) unless you're using CustomServiceHostFactory. Then whatever value you provide in address, are appended to baseaddress (.svc/..)

Comment: So if you're not using a CustomServicehostFactory then the addresses don't make a difference on server side?

Answer (score 0):

You needs to give several host name in IIS for the the same WCF and set several endpoints in the client section of web.config as:

```
    <client>
      <endpoint address="hostname1/myservice.svc" ... />
      <endpoint address="hostname2/myservice.svc" ... />
      <endpoint address="hostname3/myservice.svc" ... />
    </client>
```

Then you can consume them as:
hostname1/myservice.svc
hostname2/myservice.svc
hostname3/myservice.svc